# I am trying to list the details of a tuple with two data type how would I do this?

Tags: haskell

```
formFilmAsStringInt:: (Film,Float) -> String
formFilmAsStringInt title,director,year,likes,dislikes,number  = "Title: " ++ 
title ++ "\nDirector: " ++ director ++  "\nYear:" ++ show year ++ "\nLikes:" 
++ unwords likes ++ " \nDislikes: " ++ unwords dislikes ++"\n\n"
```

I am trying to display the the data in the tuples how do I do this? 
My film consists of (String, String , Int, [], []) and a float

```
formFilmAsStringInt title,director,year,likes,dislikes,number
```

Comment: Please provide the full code, including the Film type.

Comment: Film = (Title , Director , Year, Likes , Dislikes) - where Title, Director = String, Year = Int, Likes,Dislikes = [User] , User = String

Comment: And I want to display the information of (Film, Float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a good use of [`Text.Printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf), but you could use your code if you pattern match appropriately.

```
formFilmAsStringInt :: (Film, Float) -> String
formFilmAsStringInt ((Film title director year likes dislikes), number) =
  -- what you wrote above
```

With `printf`, I'd write:

```
import Text.Printf (printf)

formFilmAsStringInt :: (Film, Float) -> String
formFilmAsStringInt ((Film title director year likes dislikes), number) =
  let template = "Title: %s\n\
                 \Director: %s\n\
                 \Year: %d\n\
                 \Likes: %s\n\
                 \Dislikes: %s\n\n"
  in  printf template title director year likes dislikes
```

Comment: Note that you're not using `number` for anything -- why include it?

Comment: I was supposed to add the number but forgot , Thanks for your help